# How do i get to Magento Table value using API

Tags: magento-1.9, api, custom-options, table

I am using the **WebShopApps MatrixRate – #1 Multiple Table Rates Extension** for `User Selection of courier service`. I need to get this table Values by **API**. how do I get to Magento table value using API? Actually, I need this values for my DotNet Platform.

Extension Url : https://goo.gl/Lj3P3u

Answer (score 1):

I cannot provide API access, although I am loading the matrix rate shipping rates in a completely custom way - I have rewritten checkout entirely. If you are interested in loading shipping rates for a quote generated by the matrix rate module then I could answer that?

Edit with method for retrieving matrix rates:

Required:
 1. Checkout Session Quote must have a shipping address that has been saved so it has an id.
 2. This may be partially redundant but I set collect shipping rates on the quote.
 3. I load the shipping rate from the shippingRatesCollection (on the shipping address from the quote, and I take the first item since we are only enabling matrix rate), I retrieve the code for that shipping rate (which has been generated based on the quote contents and price) I then set that shipping method code on the shipping address as this is how the quote calculates overall totals and shipping prices (based on shipping by default).

Here is a segment of the code:

```
    // Hoping saving the cart (and therefore both address values will allow estimating methods)
    $this->_cart->save();

    $delivery->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates();
    $delivery->save();

    // dev
    // error handling for no delivery method available
    $method = $delivery->getShippingRatesCollection()->getFirstItem();
    $delivery->setShippingMethod($method->getCode());
    $delivery->save();
```

Comment: can you help me regard Matrix rate https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/241323/39050 @LM_Fielding